Azure - API - Lists current service health events in the tenant
I want to list current service health events in the tenant via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resourcehealth/events/list-by-tenant-id?view=rest-resourcehealth-2024-02-01&tabs=HTTP.
I created a service principle with a secret and can successfully query e.g. for those events on subscription level via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resourcehealth/events/list-by-subscription-id?view=rest-resourcehealth-2024-02-01&tabs=HTTP
I gave the service principle Reader permissions on Tenant Root Management Group level but get the error:

The client 'xxx' with object id
'xxx' does not have authorization to
perform action 'Microsoft.ResourceHealth/events/read' over scope
'/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth' or the scope is invalid. If
access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

The scope for the token request is

https://management.azure.com/

What do I need to do to successfully run the request on tenant level?

Have you added atleast Reader role to your Service Principal at Subscription level?

Reader permissions have been assigned on the Tenant Root Group, so yes, the service principal has Reader permissions on any management group and subscription within the tenant

Refer this Doc, As ,Azure Resource Health API is designed to provide health information related to resources within a specific subscription.It does not work on management group level. Scope of ServiceHealth

which type of flow you are using authorization_code or client credentials? I got response using authorization_code flow Response

Is this below solution works for you?

Initially, I registered Single Tenant Microsoft Entra ID Application, added and granted Azure Service Management API permission like below:

When I tried to reproduce same in my environment I got same error:

To resolve this error , Ensure you assigned Reader role assignment  to Service Principal at Root level:

After assigning the role assignment, Generated Access token with client credentials flow using below parameters:
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id = <client_id>
client_secret= <client secret>
grant_type = client_credentials
scope = https://management.azure.com/.default


To  Lists current service health events in the tenant:
GET https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/events?api-version=2024-02-01

In my environment,  response value is null with Status: 200 OK because,  I don't have any current Service Health event.
Reference:
List current service health events in the tenant
